# Docker installs different version of git

Tags: bash, git, docker, centos7

I'm trying to do a **container** with some tools, one of those is **git**.

I need **git 1.8.4.2** and I downloaded the tarball from here

https://github.com/git/git/archive/v1.8.4.2.tar.gz

First tried to do all the setup in a vanilla **centos:7** container to do the test and it worked very well.

The problem is when I build the container with the commands, it installs git 1.8.4.1. This version may be work with the things that I will do, but ***I'm very curious why this happens if I'm using the same tarball and same commands.***

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7

## Installing git 1.8.4.2

RUN yum -y install gcc make
RUN yum -y install wget zlib-devel openssl-devel cpio expat-devel gettext-devel curl-devel perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker
RUN wget -O v1.8.4.2.tar.gz https://github.com/git/git/archive/v1.8.4.2.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzvf ./v1.8.4.2.tar.gz
RUN cd git-1.8.4.2/ \
make prefix=/usr/local all \
make prefix=/usr/local install
```

Output when I build the container

```
[root@adbc2f7ab54f git-1.8.4.2]# git --version
git version 1.8.3.1
```

Output when I do it manually

```
root@adbc2f7ab54f git-1.8.4.2]# git --version
git version 1.8.4.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last three lines of your `Dockerfile` are specifying a single command:

```
cd git-1.8.4.2/ make prefix=/usr/local all make prefix=/usr/local install
```

...which doesn't work. As a result git 1.8.4.2 is not being compiled, it's not being installed, and the version of git in the container is the one that comes with CentOS 7 (1.8.3.1).

You need to add `&&` between the three commands:

```
RUN cd git-1.8.4.2/ \
&& make prefix=/usr/local all \
&& make prefix=/usr/local install
```

Comment: Thanks!, I think I misunderstand the \ character now it's very clear! I tested it and it works